# Copy webpage content to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, forms, copy, clipboard

I've use this resource for many things, but I have a question that I think is impossible.

I have a web form that posts to a new window.  The form and output all work fine.  What I am trying to do is make a way to copy the output (its just text) from the page to the clipboard for pasting into something else.

Currently i just drag select and copy it, but I would like to know if there is a way i can put a button or something on the page that will allow me to copy it to the clipboard.

Note:  I am NOT asking to copy a textarea input, I know how to do that.  I am asking how to copy an entire web page that has text output to the clipboard using only html, javascript, and php.  Thanks!

Comment: This is not possible with javascript. The only way you can do it is by using Flash and putting the text into Flash and getting it to copy the text to the clipboard.

Comment: Follow up: If JS could copy things to the clipboard it would also enable JS to paste things from the clipboard, this would enable sites to get info you had put in the clipboard from another source which is a crazy breach of security..

Comment: Is there a way to at least click a button to Select all?